# Random Search giving argument error? Scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

When I try to run my Random Search on the Random Forest classifier, I keep getting an error as seen below. Here is my code:

```
from sklearn.grid_search import RandomizedSearchCV

random_grid = {'criterion':['gini','entropy'],
                'n_estimators':[10, 100, 500, 750, 1000, 120],
                 'max_features':['auto', None,'sqrt','log'],
                 'max_depth':[None, 50, 75, 100],
                 'min_samples_split':[2,4,6,8,10],
                 'min_samples_leaf':[1,2,3]}

random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = classifier, param_dist = random_grid, cv=10, scoring='accuracy', n_iter=10)
random_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
random_search.best_score_              
random_search.best_params_
random_search.grid_scores_
```

The Error:

```
 File "<ipython-input-19-e1cdc27aa55f>", line 12, in <module>
    random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = classifier, param_dist = param_dist, cv=10, scoring='accuracy', n_iter=10)

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'param_dist'
```

How can I fix this issue, I see it is the parameter variable, but I dont know how else to specify it for random search

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong parameter. **param_dist** should be **param_distributions**. see: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html

i.e.

```
random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = classifier, param_distributions = random_grid, cv=10, scoring='accuracy', n_iter=10)
```

Comment: Thank you very much